# How to uninstall Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am using Mac OSX and want to uninstall/re-install(clean) hadoop

Please let me know how can I do that

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Uh, if you followed the normal install guides, just go remove all the data in the HDFS data dir, and delete everything in the hadoop directory.

Comment: My point being, that a Hadoop install is less of an install as, say, Photoshop is an install, and more you just unpack the tarball, give it some paths in the setup, and then run it. So to 'uninstall', is basically just delete the data, and delete the directory you unpacked the tarball into.